# i cant add component in angular app with cli or even manually because power shell show me this error what should i do? plz help me

Tags: angular-cli

An unhandled exception occurred: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\angular.json'
See "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-vT5z5j\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have admin access to the system.
Also please share the details of errors from the above mentioned file.

Comment: [error] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\angular.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1467:35)
    at setAnalyticsConfig (C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\analytics.js:323:10)
    at Object.promptProjectAnalytics (C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\analytics.js:402:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async _createAnalytics

Comment: (C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:55:13)
    at async Object.runCommand (C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:191:14)
    at async default_1 (C:\Windows\System32\mysecondapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js:80:31)     
                this is a detail of error and how can i check admin access to the system??

Comment: Go to Control Panel Check the Users and see CurrentUser(You) there will be written Admin.
In your case it won't be there. Please check with your manager/Lead/Technical team to grant you admin access, then the reported issue will be resolved.